# How to Actually pass parameters from API Gateway test screen to Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am learning API Gateway. I have created an API method that is linked to a lambda function. I can demonstrate that the lambda function is actually called in a timely fashion. However, when I put a query string in the "Query strings" space in the test screen and then press the Test button, the information put there does not arrive to the Lambda function. No matter what I put in there, the event handed to the Lambda comes up empty, and returns as empty. What am I doing wrong?

Lambda code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("hello")
    print("event:", event)
    print("hello")
    return event
```

Log:

```
INIT_START Runtime Version: python:3.11.v14     Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2::runtime:9c87c21a94b293e1a306aad2c23cfa6928e7a79a3d3356158b15f4cbe880b390
        START RequestId: 459979a0-f0f5-4571-9198-a5bb57ff1943 Version: $LATEST
        hello
        event: {}
        hello
        END RequestId: 459979a0-f0f5-4571-9198-a5bb57ff1943
        REPORT RequestId: 459979a0-f0f5-4571-9198-a5bb57ff1943  Duration: 1.72 ms       Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 72 MB  Init Duration: 316.97 ms
```

API setup:[image]

API test: [image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple: I didn't know my low-level HTTP very well.

Turns out that a POST request is supposed to pass its parameters via a "message body", which is a string consisting of a JSON object. (Bottom of left column in my second illustration) The default runtime environment for API Gateway doesn't even pass query strings (the stuff after the question mark in a URL) to the Lambda handler, because the message body is supposed to be handling all that.